# How can I add a table column at the first position?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

In my PostgreSQL database:

```
select index from sample;
index
---------
1
2
3
1
2
```

I want to place the `index` as below:

```
select index from sample;
index
---------
1
2
3
4
5
```

Saddam Khan provided a way to solve it:

```
alter table sample add column sort_id serial;
-- Drop column index from sample table.
alter table sample drop column index;
-- Rename column sort_id to index in sample table
alter table sample rename column sort_id to index;
-- Add Primary Key.
alter table sample add primary key(index);
```

But now,the `index` column is at the right side (end of the table). How can I place it at the left side?

```
 select * from sample;
 ticker |   roe   | income  | index 
--------+---------+---------+-------
 000820 | 2347.63 |  120.16 |     1
 300071 |  676.52 | 1035.38 |     2
 002188 |  289.69 |  273.95 |     3
 600734 |  151.58 |  921.82 |     4
 000523 |  139.94 | 2585.55 |     5
 600078 |  138.28 | 3333.41 |     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the column to an `identity` column and then update the values based on the underlying sequence.

```
-- required for an identity column
alter table sample
    alter column "index" set not null;

-- add the identity attribute - recommended over the proprietary "serial"
alter table sample
    alter column "index" add generated by default as identity;
```

Now a sequence was generated which can be used to update the existing values from to make them unique:

```
update sample
   set "index" = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('sample', 'index'));
```

Then make the column the primary key:

```
alter table sample add primary key ("index");
```

Answer (score 2):

> Add Primary Key ...

Primary Key fields are intended to be unique, **not** sequential.  If you have any kind of processing that relies on something being "ordered", **do not** rely on the Primary Key to provide it.

Can you imagine the chaos if your Bank *renumbered* people's Checking Accounts every time someone else closed *their* account?  It's a very, *very* Bad Idea.  Also, as soon as you have Foreign Keys referencing these Primary Keys, the database really should *prevent* you from doing this (and no; "cascading" changes is *not* the answer.  The amount of work that the database has to do to *make* such changes grows *exponentially* with every new referring table and all the rows in them).

> the index column is at the right-side ...

Why do you feel this matters?
Every single SELECT statement you write should specify the columns that it wants, in the order it wants them.  **Never** rely on the physical table layout because, as you've discovered, it can **change**.

Databases are inherently *share* Entities and you never know who [else] is going to be doing what in (or to?) them.

Comment: This seems to be missing that the column `index` wasn't unique to begin with. So the OP does not remove gaps in the ID space of a PK, rather replaces a broken index with a working one.

Comment: I disagree.  Re-read Saddam's "solution" - it's adding a serial column (`sort_id`), then renaming it and making it the primary key.

Comment: ... which is in line with what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

New columns are added at the end of the column list with `ALTER TABLE`. You need to recreate the table to get the desired order of columns.
**Or** `UPDATE` the existing column in place, which is slghtly tricky in the presence of a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint (while doable).

Either is expensive (for big tables) and blocking. The first option might be even cheaper overall, though more invasive. Typically a problem for DBs with concurrent access. Not a problem if you are the only user.

If you are going to write a new table, do that **instead** of all you are showing above.

Any internal references to the old table have to be dropped and recreated. Like foreign keys, views etc.

```
ALTER TABLE sample RENAME TO sample_old;

-- drop all indexes and constraints on old table to free up names
-- drop all referencing objects

CREATE TABLE sample (
  index integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, ticker text  -- use your actual data types
, roe numeric
, income numeric
);

INSERT INTO sample
      (ticker, roe, income)
SELECT ticker, roe, income
FROM   sample_old
-- no ORDER BY ??
;

ALTER TABLE sample ADD PRIMARY KEY (index);

-- recreate all indexes and constraints on new table
-- recreate all referencing objects

DROP TABLE sample_old;  -- after making sure
```

The new `IDENTITY` column is filled with auto-incremented numbers from its attached `SEQUENCE` automatically if not targeted in the `INSERT` statement. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)